# Find which input radio button is checked in code behind

Tags: asp.net, forms, listview, radio-button

I have the following ListView that contains Input radio buttons:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_BGlist">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <input id="Radio1" name="BG_name" type="radio" value="<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %  >"/>      
            <asp:Label ID="BG_fileNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_BGlist" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=tcp:cg26trmnla.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=cookniche;Integrated Security=False;User ID=PublicSQLcookniche@cg26trmnla;Password=Abounakhle80+;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT [BG_fileName] FROM [BackgroundImages]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to check which radio button is checked from code behind. I'm using the following code but it's obviously not correct.

```
 foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.ListView1.Items)
                {
                    RadioButton radioBtn = new RadioButton();
                    radioBtn = (RadioButton)itemRow.FindControl("Radio1");
                    if (radioBtn.Checked)
                    {
                        //do stuff                    
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You should use RadioButtonList instead, that would save you a lot of trouble. To continue using your code make your radio button IDs unique.

Comment: I tried the RadioButtonList and I connected it to a datasource to retrieve the values but RadioButton doesn't allow you to have html codes inside its block and I must add pictures with each list item. That's why I'm using the input type radio cause it's more flexible.....

Comment: @Gloria: then you can do it simply using jquery

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not allowed to use jquery either.....There must be a way to find my Radio button in code behind but I just don't know how....I've done it once but unfortunately I lost the code....

Comment: @Gloria : Have a look at my answer. Hope you will find your solution. Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it helps you. So that it may help other developers also.

Comment: @SpiderCode thanks for the code but after adding runat server I got an error. <input id="Radio1" name="BG_name" type="radio" runat="server" value="<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>"/>
ERROR: The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing almost right. Only few minor things needs to be changed in your code. 
Add `runat="Server"` in your radio button. Because if it will not `runat="server"` then you will not find radiobutton at code behind. have a look at below HTML code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_BGlist">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <input id="Radio1" runat="server" name="BG_name" type="radio" value="<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>"/>      
            <asp:Label ID="BG_fileNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

And in your code behind you are casting to `RadioButton` this RadioButton indicates server side control of radio button. Instead of that you should use `HtmlInputRadioButton` as shown below:

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.ListView1.Items)
{
    var radioBtn = (HtmlInputRadioButton)itemRow.FindControl("Radio1");
    if (radioBtn.Checked)
    {
        // Do Stuff                    
    }
}
```

**To Apply Grouping with RadioButton**

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input runat="server" name="BG_name" type="radio" ID="radio1" value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"  class="radioBGName" />
        <asp:Label ID="BG_fileNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.radioBGName').click(function () {

        var controlId = $(this).attr('name');
        $('.radioBGName').each(function () {
            if (controlId != $(this).attr('name')) {

                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately after adding runat=server I got the following error:  The server tag is not well formed

Comment: <input id="Radio1" name="BG_name" type="radio" runat="server" value="<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>"/>

Comment: Update your input tag as mentioned here `<input id="Radio1" name="BG_name" type="radio" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>'/>`

Comment: Thanks @SpiderCode....Now it works. I updated the answer with your suggestion: <input id="Radio1" name="BG_name" type="radio" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>'/> INSTEAD OF <input id="Radio1" name="BG_name" type="radio" value="<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %  >"/>  Note the quotation marks in Value

Comment: The only wrong behavior that remains to be solved is how to select only one button....Now I can select more than one at the same time

Comment: @Gloria : Yeh that was I meant. Glad to help you :)

Comment: for that I would suggest you to use `<Asp:RadioButton>` and provide group name into that.

Comment: I tried the <Asp:RadioButton> yesterday but it didn't help either. I also wrapped the radio buttons with <panel> as suggested by Microsoft and it didn't help either. It seems the ListView mechanism changes the groupname and assigns a different name to each button....<Asp:RadioButtonList>works well but it doesn't suit me cause the block doesn't allow hmtl codes...

Comment: I think you should use JQuery for that. That's the only solution

Comment: yes Jscript or any other script that will solve the problem in concern

Comment: @Gloria: Have a look at my updated answer. Don't forget to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("Radio1");
        if (radioBtn.Checked)
        {
           //do stuff                    
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
in `Page_Load` you need to know the row index and retrieve the control like this

```
RadioButton radio= this.ListView1.Items[<row_index>].FindControl("Radio1") as RadioButton
```

Comment: Thanks for the code......Is it possible to trigger the code on page post back? If yes how?

Comment: see the updated answer! and accept it as correct if that is the case please.